# Restart a service with dependent services?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

Starting with a [csharp-example](http://www.csharp-examples.net/restart-windows-service/) and duly noting related SO questions ( [Restart a windows services from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312656/restart-a-windows-services-from-c) and [Cannot restart a Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309990/cannot-restart-a-service-c/)) and various other questions relating to *restarting just one service*, I'm wondering what the best method is for *restarting a service **with dependent services*** (e.g. `Message Queuing`, on which `Message Queuing Triggers` depends, or `IIS`, on which `FTP Publishing` and `World Wide Web Publishing` depend). The mmc snap-in does this automagically, but the code doesn't seem to provide the same functionality (at least not as easily).

[MSDN documentation for Stop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.stop.aspx) says "If any services depend on this service for their operation, they will be stopped before this service is stopped. The DependentServices property contains the set of services that depend on this one," and [`DependentServices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.dependentservices.aspx) returns an array of services. Assuming `StartService()` and `StopService()` follow the conventions outlined in the examples and such referenced above (except that they accept `ServiceControllers` and `TimeSpans` directly), I started with:

```
public static void RestartServiceWithDependents(ServiceController service, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    ServiceController[] dependentServices = service.DependentServices;

    RestartService(service, timeout); // will stop dependent services, see note below* about timeout...

    foreach (ServiceController dependentService in dependentServices)
    {
        StartService(dependentService, timeout);
    }
}
```

But what if the service dependencies are nested (recursive) or cyclical (if that's even possible...) - if `Service A` is *depended on* by `Service B1` and `Service B2` and `Service C1` *depends on* `Service B1`, it seems 'restarting' `Service A` by this method would stop `Service C1` but wouldn't restart it...

To make this example picture clearer, I'll follow the model in the services mmc snap-in:

```
The following system components depend on [Service A]:
  - Service B1
    - Service C1
  - Service B2
```

Is there a better way to go about this, or would it just have to recursively step into and stop each dependent service and then restart them all after it restarts the main service?

Additionally, will *dependent* but *currently stopped* services be listed under DependentServices? If so, wouldn't this restart them anyways? If so, should we control that as well? This just seems to get messier and messier...

*Note: I realize the `timeout` isn't being applied completely correctly here (overall timeout could be many many times longer than expected), but for now that's not the issue I'm concerned about - if you want to fix it, fine, but don't just say 'timeout's broken...'

**Update:** After some preliminary testing, I've discovered (/confirmed) the following behaviors:

- Stopping a service (e.g. `Service A`) that other services (e.g. `Service B1`) depend on will stop the other services (including "nested" dependencies such as `Service C1`)
- [`DependentServices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.dependentservices.aspx) *does* include dependent services in all states (Running, Stopped, etc.), and it also includes nested dependencies, i.e. `Service_A.DependentServices` would contain `{Service B1, Service C1, Service B2}` (in that order, as `C1` depends on `B1`).
- Starting a service that depends on others (e.g. `Service B1` *depends on* `Service A`) will also start the requisite services.

The code above can therefore be simplified (at least in part) to just stop the main service (which will stop all dependent services) and then restarting the most-dependent services (e.g. `Service C1` and `Service B2`) (or just restarting "all" the dependent services - it will skip the ones already started), but that really just defers the starting of the main service momentarily until one of the dependencies complain about it, so that doesn't really help.

Looks for now like just restarting all the dependencies is the simplest way, but that ignores (for now) managing services that are already stopped and such...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, finally implemented this. I've posted it as a separate answer as I had already come to this conclusion in the original update to my question, which was posted prior to the first answer.

Again, the `StartService()`, `StopService()` and `RestartService()` methods follow the conventions outlined in the examples and such already referenced in the question itself (i.e. they wrap Start/Stop behavior to avoid "already started/stopped"-type exceptions) with the addendum that if a `Service` is passed in (as is the case below), `Refresh()` is called on that service before checking its `Status`.

```
public static void RestartServiceWithDependents(ServiceController service, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    int tickCount1 = Environment.TickCount; // record when the task started

    // Get a list of all services that depend on this one (including nested
    //  dependencies)
    ServiceController[] dependentServices = service.DependentServices;

    // Restart the base service - will stop dependent services first
    RestartService(service, timeout);

    // Restore dependent services to their previous state - works because no
    //  Refresh() has taken place on this collection, so while the dependent
    //  services themselves may have been stopped in the meantime, their
    //  previous state is preserved in the collection.
    foreach (ServiceController dependentService in dependentServices)
    {
        // record when the previous task "ended"
        int tickCount2 = Environment.TickCount;
        // update remaining timeout
        timeout.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(tickCount2 - tickCount1));
        // update task start time
        tickCount1 = tickCount2;
        switch (dependentService.Status)
        {
            case ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped:
            case ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending:
                // This Stop/StopPending section isn't really necessary in this
                //  case as it doesn't *do* anything, but it's included for
                //  completeness & to make the code easier to understand...
                break;
            case ServiceControllerStatus.Running:
            case ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending:
                StartService(dependentService, timeout);
                break;
            case ServiceControllerStatus.Paused:
            case ServiceControllerStatus.PausePending:
                StartService(dependentService, timeout);
                // I don't "wait" here for pause, but you can if you want to...
                dependentService.Pause();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The comment "their  previous state is preserved in the collection" is not valid. The status seemed to be updated when I was executing this code. So I had to modify it to record the initial status before the restart of the main service. Maybe .NET internal implementation has changed since this was posted?

Answer (score 2):

Please notice that `ServiceController.Stop()` stops 'dependent' services and `ServiceController.Start()` starts 'dependent on' services - thus after stopping the service you'll only need to start services that are dependency tree's leaves.

Assuming no cyclic dependencies are allowed, the following code gets services that need to be started:

```
    private static void FillDependencyTreeLeaves(ServiceController controller, List<ServiceController> controllers)
    {
        bool dependencyAdded = false;
        foreach (ServiceController dependency in controller.DependentServices)
        {
            ServiceControllerStatus status = dependency.Status;
            // add only those that are actually running
            if (status != ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped && status != ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending)
            {
                dependencyAdded = true;
                FillDependencyTreeLeaves(dependency, controllers);
            }
        }
        // if no dependency has been added, the service is dependency tree's leaf
        if (!dependencyAdded && !controllers.Contains(controller))
        {
            controllers.Add(controller);
        }
    }
```

And with a simple method (e.g. extension method):

```
    public static void Restart(this ServiceController controller)
    {
        List<ServiceController> dependencies = new List<ServiceController>();
        FillDependencyTreeLeaves(controller, dependencies);
        controller.Stop();
        controller.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
        foreach (ServiceController dependency in dependencies)
        {
            dependency.Start();
            dependency.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
        }
    }
```

You can simply restart a service:

```
    using (ServiceController controller = new ServiceController("winmgmt"))
    {
        controller.Restart();
    }
```

**Points of interest:**

For code clearity I didn't add:

- timeouts
- error-checking

Please notice, that the application may end up in a strange state, when some services are restarted and some are not...

Comment: In your if statement, you also need to check that the service is running before adding it. if (!dependencyAdded && !controllers.Contains(controller) && (controller.status != ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped && controller.status != ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending))
            
        {
            controllers.Add(controller);
        }

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to restart a "base" service and have all the things that rely on it get restarted as well. If so, you can't just restart all the dependant services, because they may not have been running beforehand. There's no API for this that I'm aware of.

The way I'd do it is just write a recursive function to scan all the dependant services (and their dependancies), and add all the services *which were running* to a list in order.

When you restart the base service, you can then just run through this list and start everything. Provided you haven't re-sorted the list, the services should start in the right order, and all will be well.

Comment: Yeah, that's the conclusion I've settled on as well... It's not terribly difficult, it's just more complicated than the automagic mmc - oh, well... :)

Comment: And it turns out it doesn't need to be recursive - note (from my update) that getting dependencies on a base lists _all_ dependent services in order of their dependency, so you'd just have to filter that list for the ones that are actually running before you restart the base...