# Sequential processing algorithm or Regex

Tags: c#, regex, algorithm

I am writing a service that basically is responsible for turning on and off other services but they need to be turned on and off in a particular order.

1. SvcMain
2. i.   SvcMasterPool1
   ii.  SvcMasterPool2
   iii. SvcMasterPool3
   ......
3. i.   SvcChildPool1 
   ii.  SvcChildPool2
   iii. SvcChildPool3
   .....

---

Here are the rules:
To stop a service:

1. If #1 is to be stopped, everything else needs to be stopped before it.
2. If anything in #2 needs to be stopped, the matching service in #3 needs to be stopped first. (SvcChildPool1 must stop before SvcMasterPool1)
3. Services in #3 can be stopped without any pre-conditions.

To start a service:
Its the exact opposite of the stopping sequence.
 1. For the services in #3 to start, the matching svc in #2 and the #1 need to be started
 2. Services in #2 need #1 to be started
 3. No pre-conditions for #1

---

The number of Master and Child Svcs can increase or decrease over time. I don't want to hard code the logic in my code and i was thinking about driving it using regular expressions. What I am stumped on is getting the matching svc from #3. If i know that i need to stop "SvcMasterPool2" how do i come up with "SvcChildPool2". I can have a regex to match all the SvcChildPoolX but cannot come up with a solution to match the equivalent child.

Any help would be appreciated or any other suggestions for a more suitable approach is welcome.

I am planning on using a database but I dont want to add the sequence for individual servers. hence the idea of using RegEx. so i just store the pattern and use it across all servers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the services are setup properly in Windows, then they can report what depends on them.

You can use the [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) to start and stop the services, and use its property [DependentServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.dependentservices.aspx) to handle starting and stopping what depends on them.

Related question:
[Restart a service with dependent services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639392/restart-a-service-with-dependent-services)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class something like this:

```
public class ServiceDependencies
{
    public string ServiceName {get;set;}
    public List<ServiceDependencies> DependsOn {get;private set;}
}
```

And make this class serializable to xml. So you have a xml file that you can easily edit with notepad and that can also easily read in by your application.

Comment: This service is going to be hosted on hundreds of servers so maintaining individual xml files is not going to be practical. I was planning on using a database but I dont want to add the sequence for individual servers. hence the idea of using RegEx.